# Cauchy problem (1+y^2)dx + (1+x^2) = 0, y(1) = 0

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Since the equation is separable, I divide it by $(1+x^2)(1+y^2) $: 
$$ \frac{1}{1 + x^2}dx + \frac{1}{1 + y^2}dy = 0$$ 
After the integration I have:
$$ \arctan y = \arctan x + C => y = \tan (C -\arctan x)$$

Solving the Cauchy problem I substitute y = 0, x =1 and find C:

$$ 0 = \tan (C -\arctan 1) => C = \frac {\pi}{4} $$

So my solution is $ y = \tan (\frac {\pi}{2} - \arctan x) $ but in the text the right solution is: $$ \frac {x+y}{1 - xy} = -3 $$

Where do I have a mistake?

UPD. The condition was fault. The right one is y(1) = 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: tangent angle addition formula.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I got a different solution: $ \arctan x + \arctan y => \tan( \arctan x + \arctan y)  => \frac {x +y}{1 - xy}  $, that is equal to 1 for y = 0, x = 1. But the answer is -3.

Comment: My fault, the condition is y(1) = 2, thus the solution is right. Thanks!